# How to return a string in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to return a string from a function using pine script but I'm getting it as an object. I'm attaching my source in below for reference

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
plot(orderType,"orderType",na)
tradeTermAlgoSyntax(price, length) =>
    emaValue = ema(price, length)
    msg = "testt"

alertcondition(true,"test",tradeTermAlgoSyntax(1,1))
plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
tradeTermAlgoSyntax(price, length) =>
    emaValue = ema(price, length)
    emaValue
plot(tradeTermAlgoSyntax(1,1))
alertcondition(true,"test", "emaValue is {{plot_0}}")
```